# How to create circle svg progress bar with dashed border

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, svg

i"m using this awesome [tutorial](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5z5vy1) for creating circle progress bar.

but my problem is that i want to change the stroke-dasharray in the CSS:

```
fill: none;
stroke: #FF2A2A;
stroke-width: 9.9213;
stroke-miterlimit: 10;
stroke-dasharray: 1.4308, 1.4308;
```

I want it to animate it like in the tutorial but to look like this image:
[Dashed border circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3s7l.png)

Comment: What do you want the final result to look like?

Comment: i edited the question.
I want it to animate it like in the tutorial but to look like this image: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3s7l.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following changes to the tutorial you mentioned:

```
progress.component.css:
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
.progress__meter {
    stroke: #4CAF50;
}

.progress__value {
    stroke: white;
    transition: all 100ms;
}


progres.component.html:
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<div class="progress">
    <svg class="progress__svg" width="120" height="120" viewBox="0 0 120 120">
        <circle class="progress__meter" [style.strokeDasharray]="5" cx="60" cy="60" [attr.r]="radius" stroke-width="11" />
        <circle class="progress__value" [style.strokeDasharray]="circumference" [style.strokeDashoffset]="1-dashoffset" cx="60" cy="60" [attr.r]="radius" stroke-width="12" />
    </svg>

    <div class="progress__value-text">{{value}}%</div>
</div>


progress.component.ts:
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
private progress(value: number) {
    const progress = value / 100;
    this.dashoffset = this.circumference * (progress);
}
```

Comment: Thank u so much! It's perfect!